# Error - class already defined

Tags: java

Pulling up a code sent to me and I'm getting 2 errors, both "class already defined"

The errors are on `Player() {`

and

`Multiplayer () {`

I've tried formating this in multiple different ways and was totally unable to get it to run.  If anyone has any suggestions please let me know, thanks in advance.

**Code is as follows:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Player {
int chances[];
boolean gameover;
int noofchances;

Player() {
    chances = new int[100];
    gameover = false;
    noofchances = 0;
}
void playgame() {
    Random r = new Random();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p;
    int i = 0;
    int guess;
    p = r.nextInt(100);
    while (i < 5) // use here while(guess == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Guess a number:"); // I used this System.out.println("Guess a number:"+p);   
        guess = sc.nextInt();
        if (guess > p)
            System.out.println("Too High.");
        else if (guess < p)
            System.out.println("Too Low.");
        else if (guess == p) {
            System.out.println("CORRECT!");
            gameover = true;
            break;
        }

        {
            chances[i] = guess;
            i++;
        }
        noofchances = i;
    }
}
void print() {
    int i;
    System.out.println("Number of responses:" + noofchances);
    for (i = 0; i < noofchances; i++)
        System.out.print(chances[i] + " ");
}
}

class MultiGame {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int noofplayers = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); // creating object to read input from keyboard
    int i;
    int playagain = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter number of users:");
    noofplayers = s.nextInt();
    Player ps[] = new Player[noofplayers]; // declaring array of player objects.
    while (playagain == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < noofplayers; i++) {
            ps[i] = new Player(); // allocating memory for the player.
            ps[i].gameover = false;
            ps[i].playgame();

        }
        for (i = 0; i < noofplayers; i++) {
            System.out.println("Player " + i + 1);
            ps[i].print();

        }
        System.out.println("Do wish to play again. Press 1 to continue.... ");
        playagain = s.nextInt();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And what is `Multiplayer`?

Comment: Btw the problem is not in posted code. It is more like that you have multiple `Player` classes in different files, but still in the same package (due to copying other code around).

Comment: You have 2 classes in the same file? Change that. It doesn't work the way you are doing it. The package probably has classes named `Player` and `Multiplayer`.

Comment: @DebosmitRay *"You have 2 classes in the same file? Change that. It doesn't work the way you are doing it."* I hope you only say that, because it is often the better structure to only have one class per file and not because you think that OPs posted code is not valid (only the posted code, not the unknown stuff in the same package).

Comment: @Tom Yea yea. That's what I meant. Like in this case, it is simply making things very obscure.

Comment: What do you mean with *get it to run*? Did you use an IDE and added the Player.java file there? Did you compile it and tried to run it with java? Do you have a classpath defined which may contain the .class and a .jar file (containing the same classes)? As mentioned several times already, your error indicates that you have the same class twice on your classpath, which cannot happen if it's just the file as your question indicates - there most be more that we don't know of.

Comment: This code compiled and ran for me in eclipse. As @Tom stated the problem is most likely that you have the `Player` class defined multiple times in the same package.

Comment: Naming a method as **print()** can be dangerous. It's a built in Java method: `System.out.print()`.